# How can I convince com.sun.faces to scan my target/classes directory for @ManagedBeans when using tomcat7:run?

Tags: maven, jsf, jsf-2, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

JSF (com.sun.faces 2.1.12) cannot find annotated classes in target/classes when run with the tomcat7 maven plugin (v2.2).

When we debug we run the application using the tomcat7:run plugin with Maven.  When the tomcat7 plugin builds the classpath for the webapp as it launches it adds target/classes to the webapp classpath as a classes directory and configures src/main/webapp as the webapp root directory.  What this means is that **there are no classes in WEB-INF/classes and the com.sun.faces annotation scanner does not scan target/classes for @ManagedBeans**.

I tried tricking the annotation scanner into scanning target/classes by adding a META-INF/faces-config.xml to src/main/resources.  This almost worked as the MET-INF/faces-config.xml was found in target/classes but com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask skipped it because it was not in a jar.  I've had difficulty finding the code that scans WEB-INF/classes.

**How can I convince com.sun.faces to scan my target/classes directory for @ManagedBeans?**

Answer (score 0):

which version of the plugin are you using?
That's normally fixed in 2.2 (see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#jarScanAllDirectories )
If not could you please create an issue with a sample project?
Thanks

Comment: @olamay, thank you for your reply.  I am using version 2.2 of the plugin (question updated).  The problem is not with scanning JARs, that is working.  The problem is that the class files with the annotation are in target/classes and not in WEB-INF/classes so they are not found my Faces' annotation because it will only look in JARs and WEB-INF/classes not not other classes directories.

Answer (score 0):

Create in your Maven project the file src/main/tomcatconf/context.xml
with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resources
        className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
        extraResourcePaths="/WEB-INF/classes=target/classes"/>
</Context>
```

The Tomcat 7 Maven plug-in looks up this file at startup. The implementation
org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext of the Context interface allows
the mapping of directories to certain resource locations. In this case we map
the directory of the project's classes to the resource /WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Roger, I was very excited about your answer as it seemed like it would work.  Unfortunately, I am unable to get it to work.  I can see where JSF eventually delegates to the ApplicationContext which does a JNDI lookup for "/WEB-INF/classes/" but it doesn't find anything under that name.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do annotations like `@Named` work? I use MyFaces 2.2.x and didn't try the `@ManagedBean` annotation.

Comment: And did you check that in your /META-INF/context.xml is no `<Resources .../>` element. Otherwise this could overwrite you configuration in /src/main/tomcatconf/context.xml.

Comment: I was mistaken before, we are using JSF 2.1.12 (I have updated the question). There are no `<Resources .../>` in the /META-INF/context.xml. I am putting a breakpoint in `com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner#processWebInfClasses(javax.servlet.ServletContext, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)` at the point where it delegates to the `ServletContext.getResourcePaths(Sting)` to get /WEB-INF/classes and it returns an empty list. So the problem seems to be with finding /WEB-INF/classes and not which annotations it is looking for. Perhaps CDI scans differently?